# Avoiding Redirection on Refresh ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, material-ui, react-router-dom

I have a web app that is built using ReactJS with react-router-dom and Firebase backend. The issue is that when the page is refreshed, the app gets redirected back to the "/" route, which I do not want. I want it to remain on the same page. For example, right now when I'm on "/settings" and click refresh, it returns to "/signin" then gets redirected to "conference/:condID" where it stays. I want it to go back to "/settings". My routing is set up as follows:

```
<Routes>
            <Route path="/signin" element={!currentUser ? <SignInScreen /> : <Navigate to="/join-conference" />} />
            <Route path="/join-conference" element={currentUser ? (!conferenceID ? <JoinConf user={currentUser} navigate={navigate} /> : <Navigate to={`/conference/${conferenceID}`} />) : <Navigate to="/signin" />} />
            <Route
              path="/conference/:confID"
              element={currentUser && conferenceID ? <ConfPage user={currentUser} /> : <Navigate to="/join-conference" />}
            />
            <Route path="/settings" element={currentUser ? <SettingsPage user={currentUser} navigate={navigate}/> : <Navigate to="/signin" />} />
            <Route exact index element={<Navigate to="/signin" />} />
          </Routes>
```

And I have a user auth useEffect set up as follows:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const unregisterAuthObserver = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      if (user) { 
        syncUsers(user);
        setCurrentUser(user);
        const data = await getUserData(user);
        if (data?.conferenceCode) {
          const conferenceCode = data.conferenceCode.slice(0, 6);
          setConferenceID(conferenceCode);
          
          // Redirect to the conference page unless on the settings page
          if (window.location.pathname !== '/settings') {
            navigate(`/conference/${conferenceCode}`);
          }
        } 
      } else {
        setCurrentUser(null);
        setConferenceID(null);
      }
      setIsLoading(false);
    });
    return () => unregisterAuthObserver();
  }, []);
```

I have tried several different approaches. The one that I used for a bit was to essentially store the state in `localStorage` so that on refresh the app would return to the same page, but this caused a whole family of routing bugs and overall just seemed like a messy solution to what I feel should be a pretty straightforward problem. For reference though, here is the code for that

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleBeforeUnload = (event) => {
      // Store the current route in localStorage
      localStorage.setItem('lastRoute', window.location.pathname);
    };

    // Attach the beforeunload event listener
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload);

    return () => {
      // Clean up the event listener when the component unmounts
      window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload);
    };
  }, []);


  useEffect(() => {
    // Check if there's a stored route in localStorage
    const lastRoute = localStorage.getItem('lastRoute');

    if (lastRoute) {
      // Navigate to the last visited route when the component mounts
      navigate(lastRoute);
    }
  }, [navigate]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Update the stored route in localStorage when the user navigates to a new route
    const unlisten = navigate((location) => {
      localStorage.setItem('lastRoute', location.pathname);
    });

    return unlisten;
  }, [navigate]);
```